# Extract Images from Word Doc or ScreenShot and Save as JPG

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to save a screenshot to an independent .jpg file, in the MS Word environment.

1. I can't save to a chart and export the chart (chart function not available in Word, only Excel).
2. I can't save as HTML and go into the created directory (only creates PNG files and can't use).
3. I can't use any function that utilizes Option Explicit (this messes other variables in my userforms).

It would be awesome if I could copy the "save as picture" function when right clicking an image in a word document in a VBA Macro.

Comment: For ```3.```, ```Option Explicit``` shouldn't mess with your code if it's properly written. It means you're probably doing some variables type transformation or dynamic (re)declaration, which can be handled (to a certain point) by the runtime but is not recommended. Actually, you should write ```Option Explicit``` in every file of your code (even in UserForms) as it checks for type compatibility and avoid dynamic declaration of variables.

Comment: I'd be glad to use Option Explicit and redraw all my code, if I could just get this capture screen shot and save as JPG function would work.   But even trying Option Explicit created macros, most of the coding that I have found after DAYS of searching, only saves the images as either a PNG, or EMF.  There was one code that I found a while back that would save to a JPG, but for some reason it saves not only the image in the word document, but all the white space to the right of it as well.

Comment: As a faster note, if I could find a way to load clipboard contents to a userform, the frame, a picture frame, a label picture, anything, that could work also.

Comment: To be clear, do you want to extract a picture included in a MS document and export it as a .jpg file ? Or do you want to take a screenshot of an area in your document and save that screenshot as a .jpg file ? Pardon me if your request is somthing totally different which I did not understand.

Comment: «I need to save a screenshot to an independent .jpg file, in the MS Word environment» jpg files have nothing to do with «the MS Word environment». The extraction of images from a docx file is as simple as changing the extension from docx to zip and extracting them from the zip archive. The extracted images will, of course, be in whatever format they had befoe they were added to the document.

Comment: Hey everyone, whoever wants to be able to do this.  Get Greenshot.  It is a freeway snipping tool and it allows you to save automatically, straight from snip to save.